Unsupervised LSTM Anomaly Detection provides no reconstruction
I am trying to use a unsupervised LSTM to detect anomaly in the data. The idea is if the reconstruction differs too much, it should categorise it as anomalous. My dataset is ['Day', 'Result]. The train dataset would have all non-anomalous data and the test dataset would have some anomalous data points.
trainX shape: (46779, 50) | trainY shape: (46779,)
testX shape: (12447, 50) | testY shape: (12447,)


Scaling:
seq_size = 50 
def to_sequences_per_day(df, seq_size=1):
    x_values = []
    y_values = []

    for day, group in df.groupby('Day'):
        day_results = group['Result'].values
        for i in range(len(day_results) - seq_size):
            x_values.append(day_results[i:(i+seq_size)])
            y_values.append(day_results[i+seq_size])

    return np.array(x_values), np.array(y_values)


Model:
# Define the model
model = Sequential()

# Encoder
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(seq_size, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(16, return_sequences=False))

# Decoder
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile the model
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mae')

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)
history = model.fit(trainX, trainX, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[early_stopping], verbose=1)

Sample dataset (not the same that i am actually using):
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Day': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3,...],
    'Result': [150, 158, 114, 120, 160, 125,...]
})

# This result will later be normalised to range from 0 to 1

Could someone suggest what might be the problem? The val loss is really low and always reach a plateau. The goal is to learn the Result pattern and reconstruct it.

If your train dataset only has "non-anomalous" results, then how can the model ever learn to distinguish between "anomalous" and "non-anomalous"? If you have a binary classification task, the training labels need to be binary too and you need both positive and negative training samples.

@mudskipper The idea is using LSTM to reconstruct what 'normal' looks like. Hence the trainX, trianX when fitting into the model. If the actual test value differs too much to what it reconstructed, it is deemed as anomalous.

I'm sorry - don't understand how I didn't see that immediately.
